# ReactJS: exporting factories, great shortcut?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering why with ReactJS it's better to create the factories on each calls (according to: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28)

Wouldn't be better to export the class and the factories ?

```
button1Class = createClass
   render: -> ...

button2Class = createClass
   render: -> ...

module.exports = { button1: button1Class, button2: button2Class}
```

Then I'll need to do

```
Button1 = createFactory( require('buttons').button1 )
Button2 = createFactory( require('buttons').button2 )
```

Each time I need them in a file (I have multiple files so multiple requires in different files) ?

Why not exporting classes and factories ?

```
button1Class = createClass
   render: -> ...

button2Class = createClass
   render: -> ...

module.exports = { 
    button1Class: button1Class, 
    button2Class: button2Class, 
    button1: createFactory( button1lass )
    button2: createFactory( button2Class )
}
```

Thus I'll only need to do

```
button1 = require('buttons').button1 # no factory needed
button2 = require('buttons').button2 # no factory needed
```

Comment: Good question, but isn't it more a npm/browserify module related question?

Comment: No I think that it's closely related to reactJS.

Comment: Okey, anyway... Imagine you only need button1, so the factory for button2 gets created also. So you have a unnecessary factory object.

Comment: Let's say that button1 and button2 are very different. I see you're point but it's not related to the question. Why do the documentation (my link) prohibit to export the factory (saying that it's '// ugly')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that it makes your exports incompatible with jsx.

You only have to create factories if you are not using jsx. But then say in your next project you want to use jsx and re-use your components you will then have to go and change the files making them incompatible with your original project.

Basically it is the consumers responsibility to create factories.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html#anti-pattern-exporting-factories

I think exporting both is an option, but creates overhead for those not using them.